# Access a view variable within a template

Tags: python, django

I have a context variable which is dynamic because of a loop I perform:

```
context['categories'] = choices.CATEGORIES
        for category_type, category in context['categories']:
            context[category_type] = Article.objects.filter(category=category_type).count()
```

But in the template it just prints the category type instead of the number which is on the variable but I also need type for a link:

```
    {% for type, category in categories %}
<a href="{% url 'app:category' type %}">{{category}}</a>
    {{type}}
    {% endfor %}
```

How can I access this dynamic variable in a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `items` method in for loop like:

```
{% for type, category in categories.items %}
    <a href="{% url 'app:category' type %}">{{ category }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: But how do I get to the {{type}} variable?